# PHP file structure array to json string only displaying first file properly

Tags: php, arrays, json, cakephp

I have a bit of code that scans a given directory and outputs the contents into an array, a sample array is as follow;

```
Array
(
    [0] => docker-vs-vagrant.png
    [floor] => Array
        (
            [moretesting] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Webserver_requests_graph.jpg
                )

        )

    [plans] => Array
        (
            [0] => Screen Shot 2017-10-09 at 7.08.52 pm.png
        )

    [1] => screenshot.png
    [screenshots] => Array
        (
        )

    [test] => Array
        (
            [0] => Screen_Shot_2017-10-09_at_4_52_32_pm.png
        )

    [test2] => Array
        (
            [0] => testScreen Shot 2017-10-09 at 7.08.52 pm.png
        )

)
```

As you can tell, the files marked with the keys [0] and [1] are in the root directory, and everything else is organised into folder structure.

The code I am using to generate this array is as follows;

```
function dirToArray($dir) {
    $contents = array();

    foreach (scandir($dir) as $node) {
        if ($node == '.' || $node == '..') continue;

        if (is_dir($dir . '/' . $node)) {
            $contents[$node] = $this->dirToArray($dir . '/' . $node);
        } else {
            $contents[] = $node;
        }
    }

    return $contents;
}
```

After this I am using a inbuilt cakephp function to flatten the array so it looks like the following;

```
Array
(
    [0] => docker-vs-vagrant.png
    [floor.moretesting.0] => Webserver_requests_graph.jpg
    [plans.0] => Screen Shot 2017-10-09 at 7.08.52 pm.png
    [1] => screenshot.png
    [test.0] => Screen_Shot_2017-10-09_at_4_52_32_pm.png
    [test2.0] => testScreen Shot 2017-10-09 at 7.08.52 pm.png
)
```

After that i need to format it into json that my javascript api can read, the function to do this is as follows;

```
function flatArrayToJsonString($flatArray)
{
    $arrayId = 1;
    $final_array = [[0, '/', '/', false]];

    foreach ($flatArray as $key => $val) {
        if ($key == '0') {
            $final_array[] = [$arrayId, '/' . $val, $val, true];
            $arrayId++;
        } else {
            $exploded_key = explode('.', $key);
            foreach ($exploded_key as $k => $v) {
                if ($v == '0') {
                    $dots = '.. ';
                    for ($i = 0; $i < count(array_slice($exploded_key, 0, $k)); $i++) {
                        $dots .= '.. ';
                    }
                    $final_array[] = [$arrayId, '/' . join('/', array_slice($exploded_key, 0, $k)) . '/' . $val, $dots . $val, true];
                    $arrayId++;
                } else {
                    $dots = '.. ';
                    for ($i = 0; $i < count(array_slice($exploded_key, 0, $k)); $i++) {
                        $dots .= '.. ';
                    }
                    $final_array[] = [$arrayId, '/' . join('/', array_slice($exploded_key, 0, $k + 1)), $dots . $v, false];
                    $arrayId++;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return json_encode($final_array);
}
```

The final result that is being returned to me is as follows;

```
[
    [0,"\/","\/",false],
    [1,"\/docker-vs-vagrant.png","docker-vs-vagrant.png",true],
    [2,"\/floor",".. floor",false],
    [3,"\/floor\/moretesting",".. .. moretesting",false],
    [4,"\/floor\/moretesting\/Webserver_requests_graph.jpg",".. .. .. Webserver_requests_graph.jpg",true],
    [5,"\/plans",".. plans",false],
    [6,"\/plans\/Screen Shot 2017-10-09 at 7.08.52 pm.png",".. .. Screen Shot 2017-10-09 at 7.08.52 pm.png",true],
    [7,"\/1",".. 1",false],
    [8,"\/test",".. test",false],
    [9,"\/test\/Screen_Shot_2017-10-09_at_4_52_32_pm.png",".. .. Screen_Shot_2017-10-09_at_4_52_32_pm.png",true],
    [10,"\/test2",".. test2",false],
    [11,"\/test2\/testScreen Shot 2017-10-09 at 7.08.52 pm.png",".. .. testScreen Shot 2017-10-09 at 7.08.52 pm.png",true]
]
```

This works perfect only if there is 1 file in the root or any of the subdirectories.

But once another file is added it breaks.

You can see that the following value;

```
[1] => screenshot.png
```

is in the wrong place, and in the final output is broken, being displayed as;

```
[7,"\/1",".. 1",false],
```

as im trying to display a hierarchy, this should displayed like so;

```
[1,"\/docker-vs-vagrant.png","docker-vs-vagrant.png",true],
[2,"\/screenshot.png","screenshot.png",true],
```

The description of the final output is as follows;

```
[id, fullpath, displayname, leaf]
```

where leaf means if it is a file or a directory.

Im sorry its such a big post, but im stumped on how to go about fixing this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you build the final array structure directly when iterating over the filesystem, why all these steps in between?

Comment: @ndm I wouldn't know how to go about doing what you mentioned ... the code i posted is pieced together and its hard enough for me to understand as is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is that it's prepared to deal only with one file per folder. It not only breaks if you have more than one file in the root folder, but the same will happen for subfolders.

It will also break if any of your folders holds a subfolder named "0".

The following code fixes these problems:

```
function flatArrayToJsonString($flatArray)
{
    $arrayId = 1;
    $final_array = [[0, '/', '/', false]];
    ksort($flatArray, SORT_STRING);  // Sort the flat array by keys

    foreach ($flatArray as $key => $val) {
        $exploded_key = explode('.', $key);
        foreach ($exploded_key as $k => $v) {
            if ($k == sizeof($exploded_key)-1) { // last element of exploded key is always a file
                $dots = '.. ';
                for ($i = 0; $i < count(array_slice($exploded_key, 0, $k)); $i++) {
                    $dots .= '.. ';
                }
                $final_array[] = [$arrayId, '/' . join('/', array_slice($exploded_key, 0, $k)) . '/' . $val, $dots . $val, true];
                $arrayId++;
            } else {
                $dots = '.. ';
                for ($i = 0; $i < count(array_slice($exploded_key, 0, $k)); $i++) {
                    $dots .= '.. ';
                }
                $final_array[] = [$arrayId, '/' . join('/', array_slice($exploded_key, 0, $k + 1)), $dots . $v, false];
                $arrayId++;
            }
        }
    }

    return json_encode($final_array);
}
```

I have tried to modify your code as little as possible to make it functional. However, there are much better ways of solving your problem.

Note that your code is flawed from the start. Flattening the array with `Hash::flatten()`isn't a good idea, as it **will make the code break if your folder names contain a dot**. You could use a different separator (e.g. a character or string that you know your file system won't be using). Nevertheless, it is always better to work with associative arrays or objects.

You should explore other options, like doing everything in one go when iterating over the file system (as suggested by @ndm in the comments).

Comment: Hey, that sort of works ... But the file that has an id of 7 should be under the file with an id of 1 as they are both in the root directory ... Is there a way to group them like a hierarchy?

Comment: You can sort the array before processing it. This can be done with `        ksort($flatArray, SORT_STRING)`. I've edited the code to add this line.

Comment: Ok, that has worked perfectly ... I know the code isn't good, and i'll refactor later, but i just needed to get this out ASAP ... Thank you so much for your help, i really do appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Do you particularly need to flatten the array? Because if not, you could literally just have this:

```
function flatArrayToJsonString($flatArray)
{
    return json_encode($flatArray); //returns string
}
```

and then do appropriate formatting in javascript.

However, i don't recommend flattening the original array, as it has directory structure/hierarchy in the layout of your original array before you flatten it with cakephp.

Edit: Also to have an id doesn't quite make sense in a lot of scenarios, because files and directories could be added or removed, invalidating any id's originally sent through by php. Perhaps you should re-look at your current approach to the problem